# Logout after a specific idle time in ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I am creating a web application in the **Blazor** Server version in .NET 6. For authentication, I am using **ASP.NET Core Identity**. Now I need a feature in my application. If the application is Idle for a specific time (like 10 min), it will log out. I have added the below code in my `Program.cs` file. But the problem is after the specific time span if I refresh the application then it logs out. But if I click any link of the app, nothing happens.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.Name = "Horus";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/account/logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

What else I should do to logout if I click any link? And another thing is this line

```
options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
```

really counts the idle time? Let me know please.

Comment: the links which you click - make sure these links are not public. Meaning they should be requiring authentication by Identity only then you will be redirected on clicking them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Prefer to use JavaScript for these situations, you can use `Timer` to count idle state seconds, if the timer ends then you should fire a handler that logs the user out without even the need to click any link or do anything.

If that's fine with you, follow these steps:

1- Create a JavaScript file in `wwwroot/js` directory with an appropriate name (eg: `auth-helper.js`) with the following content:

```
function initializeInactivityTimer(dotnetHelper) {
    var timer; 
    //the timer will be reset whenever the user clicks the mouse or presses the keyboard
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;

    function resetTimer() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(logout, 600000); //600,000 milliseconds = 10 minuts
    }

    function logout() {
        dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync("Logout");
    }

}
```

2- Add a script tag in `~/Pages/_Layout.cshtml` for .NET 6 or in `~/Pages/_Host.cshtml` for .NET 5:

```
<script src="./js/auth-helper.js"></script>
```

3- Add logging out implementation and the call of the `initializeInactivityTimer` JS function in `MainLayout`, and make sure to add it to `MainLayout` not to a page or component so you make sure that the `DotNetObjectReference` is alive whenever it called:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //Start the timer for idle state
    await js.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeInactivityTimer", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
}


[JSInvokable]
public async Task Logout()
{
    var authState = await AuthenticationState;
    if (authState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //implement the logging out process here
        //this might be navigation to the Logout page 
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you use Azure B2C. It's giving me the following error:
```There was an error trying to log you out: 'The logout was not initiated from within the page.'```

Super frustrating that this simple functionality is so difficult to implement.

Comment: I'm sorry @Sean, I haven't worked with Azure B2C before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answer (i.e. to use JS) is dangerous!  All you need to do is disable JS in the browser or manually change the timeout value client-side and you are logged in forever!  Any Blazor question that is answered with "JavaScript" should be viewed with caution.

But because it appears to work, people will accept it and use it!

There is a constant feedback loop between the server (IIS) and a user (browser) with Blazor (unlike traditional ASP.NET which relies on postbacks\ajax) so if you kill the user session off on the server, probably best done by having a "last activity" variable that is updated whenever the user does something and if that gets too old it kills the session, it will end the feedback loop logging the user out. You just need to handle that on the client.